# How can I do a find-and-replace across my whole system?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed, grep

I want to run a query or script which first searches every `.php` file on my system for the string `strawberry`. If that string is found anywhere, *the entire line containing it* should be replaced with the string `pineapple`. I only have access to bash, no Ruby/Python/more flexible language.

I'm sure that there's a way to do this, but I can't figure it out. I can't even figure out the grep command to start it... `grep -Rl "strawberry" .` seems to return every single file in the directory, even those that don't contain the string 'strawberry' at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linux command line : edit hacked index files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5750284/linux-command-line-edit-hacked-index-files)

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/questions/218005/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: Ignore the `R` option for grep, it was a bad idea. The UNIX tool to find files is named `find`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really want to, and probably don't have write access everywhere.

```
find / -type f -name '*.php' -exec sed -i 's/.*strawberry.*/pineapple/' {} \;
```

If you are trying to clean up a malware infection or break-in, the proper way to do that is to bring your site off-line, fix the attack vector, harden your system, audit your scripts, and restore the rest from known-good backups

Comment: This will change the modification time on all PHP files, regardless of whether they matched the search string or not. I would consider that a major issue...

Comment: Depends on what sort of panic you're in. I strongly suspect that the latter part of my answer is the real answer to this particular use case.

Comment: If you have been hacked, that's an *even worse* time to be mucking with timestamps blindly... Not to mention the fact that a simple search & replace will probably not a definite cure anyway...

Comment: Why do you suspect a hacked system, anyway? The OP could just want to change the branding of their website, or something...

Comment: And just to reiterate, you should not be doing anything at all like this then.

Comment: Look at the duplicates. They are basically *all* from hacked site owners. What sort of rebranding effort would use this approach, anyway?

Comment: Uh, I honestly can't see how these are duplicates... There can be legitimate reasons to mass-edit code you know. For example, I used what I wrote in my answer recently to update the copyright strings in my code base...

Comment: +1 but you could add the `-perm` arg for `find` to test file permissions so it only invokes `sed` on files that ARE writeable.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
grep -RlZ "strawberry" /srv/www | 
    grep -z '.*\.php$' |
    xargs -r -0 sed -i 's|.*strawberry.*|pineapple|'
```

To explain things a little, the first [`grep(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) invocation of the pipeline is invoked with the following options:

- `-R`: recurse over directories, following any symlinks. Note the difference with `-r`.
- `-l`: output any matching file name.
- `-Z`: suffix any output file names with a zero byte. This is used to ensure that names with whitespace etc. are handled correctly.
- `/srv/www` is the path to the top of the directory hierarchy that you want to search. You should avoid using `/` here - you probably don't want to do that, *especially* if you are doing this with `root` privileges.

The second `grep` filters out any non-PHP files. The `-z` option instructs it to use the zero byte as the line (i.e. file name) separator instead of the newline character.

The last part uses [`xargs(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xargs) to execute [`sed(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed):

- The `-r` option for `xargs` just suppresses an error if no matching files are found.
- The `-0` option for `xargs` lets it know that the input items are separated by a zero byte.
- The `-i` option for `sed` instructs it to perform an in-place replacement of the matching files.
- Finally the substitution expression `s|.*strawberry.*|pineapple|` translates as "any string, followed by *strawberry*, followed by any string should be replaced with the string *pineapple*".

This however is not the most efficient way to perform this search - the first `grep` will happily search each and every file, rather than just the PHP files. A more efficient way would use [`find(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) to filter the file names beforehand:

```
find -L /srv/www -type f -name '*.php' -print0 |
    xargs -r -0 grep -lZ "strawberry" |
    xargs -r -0 sed -i 's|.*strawberry.*|pineapple|'
```

Please note the `xargs`/`grep` part - it is used to prevent files that do *not* contain the search string from being filtered through `sed`, as that would at least change their modification times and possibly create other issues. As a principle, *always be as specific as possible when issuing recursive commands*...

I leave the rest explanation as an exercise to the reader :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `gawk` version `4.1`, you could use [`inplace` extension](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Extension-Sample-Inplace.html) with `bash`'s `globstar` option to search recursively.

```
shopt -s globstar
gawk -i inplace '/strawberry/{$0="pineapple"}1' /dir/**
```

Comment: That could be written as just `{print (/strawberry/ ? "pineapple" : $0)}` or even `/strawberry/{$0="pineapple"} 1`.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to steal that for my update.  I've been known to write oddly long code when I'm tired.